Why only 3 fundamental Particles make up most of what we can perceive?
Why are there versatile things with ordinary matter (atoms)?
Just 3 particles of the 12 - their combination makes up most of what we perceive as world (let's ignore dark matter and dark energy as we are not sure with which particles they are made of or include them)
Why did they become (or are) stable enough to form matter while other particles do not?
(I learnt that only up quark, down quark and electrons are stable to form matter from a language model, so not so sure about it's integrity)
Can this be fundamentally explained with String Theory?

what are the three particles you are referring to? Theories in physics do not "explain". They are mathematical models used to fit measurements and data, and are considered good if they have predictive power and successfully predict  new measurements and data,

Fundamental in what sense?

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. Are you asking why familiar baryonic matter is made of up and down quarks and electrons instead of all known quarks and leptons? If so, it's because neutrinos interact too weakly to be bound, and another six fermions decay to lighter particles.

For once, the AI didn’t mislead you (it’s a simple enough concept, I suppose). There are four “stable” particles (ignoring neutrino oscillations), which are all of the lowest mass in their respective families. If you increase the mass to get other particles, the new particle becomes unstable and just decays back down (usually quite quickly).

Voting to reopen. We can answer why other particles are not present in ordinary matter. Most are not stable. Neutrinos do not interact in the right way to bind to ordinary matter.

@mmesser314 It seems OP wants to know whether ST can predict which particles are stable and what is the explanation given to that in the ST framework.

Do not forget about the anti-quarks and positrons! Those are technically stable, until they come into contact with normal matter.

He does not say which, but I think he means up, down quarks and electrons. Although then I can only think of 9 potential candidates...
